# Can Bridge or Photoshop print multiple photos automatically?

Tags: photoshop, printing, workflow, adobe-bridge

Is there a way to get Bridge or Photoshop to print a bunch of photos automatically, without clicking "print" for each individual photo?

It would be best if I could do this one photo to a page.

Ideally, I'd like to apply the same workflow / filter sequence to each photo before printing it.

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop has an entire automation workflow that you can use to automate batch operations.  It would be ideal for what you are trying to do here.

These batch operations are called Actions and you can get to them from the Windows...Actions menu.

[image]

You then make a new action

[image]

and name it.

[image]

You can then record the steps you want to do, opening the file, applying any filters and printing.

[image]

When finished, hit the Stop to save the action.

[image]

Now that we have an action we can use that action as part of a batch operation against all the files you want to apply it to.  You do this by going to the File...Automate...Batch menu.

[image]

Choose our action from the drop down and select which files you want to open.  Be sure to check the override open action button if you had an open step in your action.

[image]